# Start Thread multiple times

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to use a thread to upload a file to a server.

As long as the `ThreadState` is `Unstarted`, I can use `ThreadName.Start()` to start the thread.
When the code is finished the `ThreadState` gets `Stopped`.
How can I start that thread again?

My thread looks like this:

```
public static Thread ThreadUploadFile = new Thread(() =>
{
    // Upload file
});
```

I call the thread by:

```
private void UploadFile()
{
    ThreadUploadFile.Start();
});
```

Comment: As a side note, tasks are more convenient than threads. `var task = Task.Run(() => { /* Upload file */ });`

Comment: It also could be, that you don't need to start threads at all. It depends on how you upload your files. Maybe there are some async methods of the classes used. How does your upload looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot.

Once the thread is stopped then it can never leave that state.
You must initialise a new instance and run that new instance.

See
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadstate?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0

I also found this picture (I am not sure if it is still 100% correct).

[image]

Comment: thread pool can also be used for the similar purpose

Comment: Use tasks that will use a threadpool

Answer (score 1):

You cannot start the Thread again once it is stopped.
I recommend to turn your anonymous method into a real method and create a new Thread each time before starting.